# Munin not generating graphs

Tags: perl, ubuntu-12.04, munin

My clean munin install is not generating graphs, i did everything listed in this URL to debug

http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/FAQ_no_graphs#Ijustreadtheaboveanswerandtherestillarentanygraphs

i can successfully connect via telnet to the node.

-The nodes comand display the node correctly

-The list command shows the list of plugins correctly.

-The fetch command provides an empty output!!!

i opened the munin-node.log file to see what's going on, and every entry logs (i think 1 entry for every plugin) show one of this 2 error messages (when i restart the node the error switch from one to another)

1-
Error output from threads:
2013/08/08-07:38:04 [2659]      Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/share/perl5/Munin/Node/Service.pm line 241.
2013/08/08-07:38:04 [2659] Service 'threads' exited with status 255/0.

2-
Error output from vmstat:
2013/08/08-07:35:02 [1096]      2013/08/08-07:35:02 [1186] Died at /usr/share/perl5/Munin/Common/Timeout.pm line 66,  line 74.

i have no clue, of how to solve this.

Im using Ubuntu 12.04 and the installed munin version is the 1.4 ... since the 2.x are not available for ubuntu 12.04

---

Maybe someone with experience with pearl could orient me on how to edit the source to get rid of the error!!!

Comment: "The fetch command provides an empty output!!"  - you'd use fetch followed by the name of a plugin. Was output empty when calling fetch with plugin name?